# SonarQube Web api lastAnalysis date

Tags: sonarqube, webapi

I would like to generate a report regarding SonarQube projects' last analysis dates. I am using this web api of SonarQube:  `https://sonarqube_server.com/api/project_branches/list?project=test.project`
. Normally, it show the JSON result and this is the output on `analysisDate "2023-09-28T23:37:27+0000"`.

So the format was YYYY-MM-DD-THH:MM:SS, the problem here was the HH has different value upon comparing on the SonarQube UI, UI Shows: `September 29, 2023 at 7:37 AM`. Why is that the API Call shows different time in terms of hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api response in UTC "2023-09-28T23:37:27**+0000**" and you are probably in UTC+8 hours.
Browser send yoour local so you get the right time.

Comment: Hi @Mr_Thorynque , appreciate your answer, so does it means the API response depends on the user who executes it?

Comment: No API response with UTC  that's your browser which convert it to local time.